# Is an exact copy + paste of the code in a question as an answer, an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-answer

I recently came across a question with [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51248983/6275781) like:

> You are doing {something}. What do you expect?
>
> {code from question}

I flagged, which was disputed. Later I noticed the question was upvoted.

I ran into [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22403184/6275781) today which was *only* a copy + paste of the code from the question as answer. I was shocked to see it had 11 upvotes and only one downvote.

Are these kinds of answers acceptable? Why aren't they considered not an answer?

Comment: If it is *only* copy paste without attribution I call it plagiarism which is a mod-flagable offense. For the other cases I would also have used a custom-mod flag: explain what the problem is, that it probably get missed when normally reviewed, that a delete is warranted and that you can't rule out suspicious voting. You must be blatantly wrong if that flag gets declined, even if the answer doesn't get deleted.

Comment: Did the code answer the question?  The fact that it has 11 upvotes either implies that it did, or likely voter fraud.  It's not unheard of for people to ask a question that has the answer to their own question in their question.

Comment: The problem with using NAA flags on answers like that is that they appear to be an attempt to answer if you don't check the question. Too many posts end up in that queue because they're mostly/only code so it looks like that's the reason it's there.

Comment: @pnuts I added the examples. I didn't want to because I wanted a more generic answer for just copying the code from the question, but examples are nice.

Comment: @pnuts Oh no, I got nothing for that. I can't think of a good reason an answer post that's just copy/paste of the broken code in the question would get 11 up votes.

Comment: @Servy I don't think they attempt to answer the question. Which is why I'm here because my flag was disputed and the answers seem well received. I added the two answers to the body, maybe others are a better judge than I am.

Comment: The first one does not say that line of code will solve the problem, it says it *is* the problem (just pointing to it). I don't see an issue of plagiarism there.

Comment: I guess eleven different people lost their keys?